# Infopath data submit into sharepoint form library

Tags: infopath

Hi getting the following error message while submitting InfoPath form to Sharepoint forum Library. Please give step by step answer how to resove the bellow issue.

******InfoPath cannot submit the form.
An error occurred while the form was being submitted.
The form cannot be submitted to the following location:
The folder does not exist************

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct URL?
Do you have permissions to do what you're trying to do?
Is WebDAV service allowed for your user?